# A JavaScript vulnerability - "this"-stealing:

Tags: javascript, google-caja

I'm learning about Caja, and I am confused about the concept of "this"-stealing:

> Another security vulnerability that Caja addresses is called “this”
>   stealing – if an object’s clients can add methods to the object’s
>   state which alias its “this” then the aforementioned protected “this”
>   rule does not apply.

Then they show the following constructor:

```
function Cell(value) {
  this.x_ =  "secret";
  this.value = value;
}
```

There's a hidden leak involving "x_" :

The following code can make the expression reveal that secret value:

```
(new Cell(
  function (){
    return this.x_;
  })).value()
```

How does this work?  Why is it such a problem? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify it:

```
(new Cell( )).value()
```

We're creating a new object from the Cell constructor, and immediately calling its value method. Of course the value method doesn't do anything yet, which is where our next portion comes in:

```
function (){ 
  return this.x_; 
}
```

This is what we're passing into the constructor as the `value` parameter. This function is assigned to `this.value` within the Cell constructor.

So the Cell constructor effectively looks like this now:

```
function Cell(value) {
  this.x_ =  "secret";
  this.value = function (){ 
    return this.x_; 
  };
}
```

So what happens when you create a new object from Cell, and call its `value` member? A function from within returns the Cell object's `x_` value, thus revealing the secret text.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Jonathan - I got it now! JavaScript is quite powerful!

Comment: If I want to be `x_` a secret, I declare it as `var x_ = "secret";`, not as `this.x_ = "secret";`. The "attack" stops to work immediately in this case. Anything I bind to `this` in an object constructor is *by definition* not a secret. I can even enumerate it freely with `for .. in`, without the need to bend over backwards to see its value. I don't get it - where is the point in all of this?

Comment: @Tomalak I was wondering about that myself. The code from the book definitely does present the best example, but it's clear what the intent was.

Comment: @Tomalak - This is from the main Caja paper, http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/downloads/detail?name=caja-spec-2008-06-07.pdf .   Later  in the paper, they say that because of the "this" issue, Caja divides functions into three categories: simple functions, constructors, and methods. Simple functions are those which do not mention “this”. They can be used without any further restriction because they are first-class. Constructors are named functions that contain “this”. Lastly, methods are anonymous functions which mention “this”.

Comment: @Adel This is nice and correct, but it does not address my point. Besides, the three categories you speak of are not exactly a *Caja invention*. Anyone with some insight into how JS objects work would come to the same conclusion. The whole "attack vector" of `this`-stealing does not exist, at least not in the form your example suggests. It is simply impossible to steal something *really* secret from a JS object.

Comment: @Tomalak -  I understand what you mean now. Maybe the authors were "stretching" a bit, to demonstrate what Caja can do? Thank You Very Much Tomalak

Comment: @Adel I see the use of tool-based checks for common mistakes and sloppy coding. But `this.x = "secret";` is just that: sloppy coding. It's not an exploitable vulnerability of JavaScript itself, that's the point I wanted to make.

Comment: @Jonathan: Just to nitpick some more - your second code sample is not *really* how the constructor effectively looks like. The function *defined in* the constructor has a different scope than the one *passed to* it as a parameter. The former would be able to see a `var x_`, the latter wouldn't.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm aware of that. The first thing that came to my mind when I read the title of this question was that we would be using something like `call` instead. The *effectively* example was the best I knew to represent what was kind of going on. If it's entirely wrong, please feel free to improve.

Comment: @Tomalak - Hmm I see. I realize I do need to study more JavaScript ! Thank You So Much!

Comment: @Tomalak Caja is a modified runtime and a restricted form of JavaScript that is intended to provide more security. Fields with the underscore prefix are only allowed via a `this` reference. It further restricts this access to either constructors (only callable by new) and anonymous function assigned to a prototype. `this` stealing is only meaningful in this context. Allowing the methods referencing `this` to be passed in as a constructor parameter could allow the method to steal a underscore value from the object. Disallowing `this` referencing methods in this fashion preserves the constraint.

Comment: @chuckj And what about `call()` and `apply()`? I could entirely spare me the hassle of "passing in functions to a constructor", and just directly execute them in the target object's context. Which would give me the same access to that object's `this`. This is still no attack. (But thanks for the clarification, I was unaware of that underscore suffix convention.)

Comment: @Tomalak A function containing `this` references can only be assigned directly to a prototype or called with `new`. This bans both `call()` and `apply()` as well. You are right, there is no such attach in standard JavaScript. Caja is not standard JavaScript. `this` stealing only is a threat if you are trying to run untrusted JavaScript in the same context with trusted JavaScript which is what Caja provides for.

Comment: Even if one object can't access another objects vars, just add a breakpoint (there's no such things as explicit scoping). Besides I don't see any advance in using proprietary embedding solutions like this. Client-side security with JavaScript not really exists, server-side measures are the only thing that really grabs.